# Java - Swing GUI Window Order

Tags: java, windows, swing

In the following code, why is the "My Application" window the window at the front? The main method constructs this window first, right? So shouldn't it be at the back when the "My Window" JFrame is produced?

```
public class MyApp extends JFrame {
public MyApp() { 
super();
setSize(300,600); 
setTitle("My Application"); 
setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) { 
MyApp application = new MyApp(); 
JFrame window = new JFrame(); 
window.setSize(600,300); 
window.setTitle("My Window"); 
window.setVisible(true);
} 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply undefined behavior; there's no guarantee that *either* window will always be in front. When I ran your code (Mac OS X, Java 6), "My Window" came up in front, but I have no doubt you're correctly describing what happens on your system.

Answer (score 1):

1) you can't move one JFrame `toFront()` over another `JFrame`

2) don't create more than one `JFrame`, there are another issues with this `Top-Level Container` as `toFront`, `toBack`

3) you have look at `JDialog` or `JWindow` as another Window

- with `parent` to the `JFrame`
- with `setModal` if required
- with `ModalityTypes` is required

Comment: @Tharwen [did you read this code there are two instances of JFrames](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/714968)  1) first `MyApp extends JFrame`, 2) second `JFrame window = new JFrame();` 3) both are visible out of `InitialThread`

Comment: I didn't mean that it was wrong! Just that it doesn't specifically answer the question: "why is the "My Application" window the window at the front?"